# Questions about Memory Management, Stack, and Heap

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does this type of memory get allocated on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426737/does-this-type-of-memory-get-allocated-on-the-heap-or-the-stack)

I have a few memory-related questions, I was hoping you guys would be able to answer.  Consider this code, with **Foo** representing a large class with lots of methods and lots of primitive data members:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo() : // Initialize all data members ...
        { }

    // Lots of methods ...

    ~Foo() { /*Nothing needed here ... correct?*/ }

private:
    int    a;
    int    b;
    char   c;
    double d;
    // Lots of other primitive data members (no pointers) ...
};

class Bar {
  public:
    void func() {
        foo = new Foo();
    }

    // Assuming Bar::func() is always called before deletion ...
    ~Bar() { delete foo; }
  private:

    Foo* foo;
};

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    bar.func();

    Bar* barptr;
    barptr->func();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, when I call `bar.func()`, are all the data members of `Foo` allocated on the **stack** memory or on the **heap** memory (I know `foo` would be on the heap...I think!)? What about when I call `barptr->func()`? Is, for example, `Foo::a` on the stack or on the heap?

Furthermore, do I need to explicitly delete anything in `Foo::~Foo()`? **Foo** only has primitive local data members, and none of the functions use `new` or `malloc()`.

In the case that I have absolutely no idea what I'm talking about, I'd appreciate it if someone could explain where these data are stored.

Comment: @sehe:  I suspect it is an artifact of Microsoft's text representation.

Comment: Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization describes why destructors are commonly empty when C++ is done right.

Comment: @sehe:  Are you sure?  The phenomena doesn't occur on my Linux-based browser's copy and paste operations, but it occasionally occurred on Windows.  Don't know why it did not happen every time—maybe there is some internal hack to fix it.

Comment: @wallyk: I hope SO proposes to go to chat, I don't know how to do that. I use Opera on linux 90% of the time. It sure copies all SO text to the clipboard with CRLF - I need to `:%s/^M//g` all the time in vim

Comment: The extra whitespace is just a coding style. It wasn't the artifact of anything.

Comment: To be entirely pedantic, one would have to add that any of the answers only apply if you didn't provide any per-class new and delete operators, or if you were to change your code to say `::new`. Otherwise who knows what's going on (other than you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything allocated with `new` is on the heap, including all its members.  The line `foo = new Foo();` creates a Foo (including *all* its members) on the heap.
Only named objects are on the stack.  In your case `bar` (a `Bar`), and `barptr` (a pointer to a `Bar`).
`Foo`s destructor doesn't need to do anything, which is actually quite common, if you use RAII  properly, like is the C++ way.

In your `main` function, `bar` is a region on the stack that is a `Bar`, which allocates a `Foo` on the heap.  If `barptr;` were actually initialized, `barptr` would be a region on the stack that is a pointer to a `Bar` somewhere (maybe stack maybe not).  However, in every case, a `Bar`s `foo` member will be allocated on the heap, since that's what `Bar`s constructor tells it to do.

In your `main` function, `bar` is a region on the stack that is a (pointer to a (large collection of primitives)), which allocates a (large collection of primitives) on the heap.
If `barptr;` were actually initialized, `barptr` would be a region on the stack that is a pointer to a (pointer to a (large collection of primitives)) somewhere (maybe stack maybe not).  However, in every case, the (large collection of primitives) will be allocated on the heap, since that's what the constructor tells it to do.

Since I know someone will mention it, the heap/stack distinction is at the compiler's whim, and not standardized in any way.  It is fully allowed to "cheat" and put things in other places if it feels like it.  For instance, global objects are frequently on neither the stack nor the heap, but in another place.  Also, that's how C# and java go so fast despite the frequent (apparent) use of memory management.  The compiler frequently "cheats" and puts "dynamically scoped" objects on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

When you call new Foo(), you're creating a new Foo object on the heap.

All the primitive data members in Foo are stored inside the Foo object. Therefore, they are also on the heap -- inside the Foo object.

Your Foo destructor doesn't need to explicitly dispose of the primitive data members. Nor would it need to explicitly dispose of members of class type; their destructors would be called automatically after Foo's destructor.

A class that has a bare pointer to something dynamically allocated typically does need an explicit statement in the destructor to dispose that something. You can avoid this by using smart pointers like `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr.`