# Member function memory allocation stack or heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm trying to allocate an array as follows:

```
class foo{
public:
    void func(){double arr[13][64][64][64];}
};

int main()
{
    foo* inst = new foo();
    inst->func();       
    return 0;
}
```

I was under the impression from answer such as:
[Does this type of memory get allocated on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426737/does-this-type-of-memory-get-allocated-on-the-heap-or-the-stack)
that the array arr would be placed on the heap (as the instance of the class is on the heap).  This doesn't seem to be the case as I get a segmentation fault.  If I change a's declaration to:
    double* arr = new double[13*64*64*64];
(and delete it properly) then everything's fine.

What's happening here?

Comment: indirectly, the array would get allocated dynamically (because foo is dynamically allocated) - however, it's very unclear to me what you want to achieve with this unused variable in `foo`?

Comment: @nyarlathotep - Jack created a minimum working example to illustrate his problem.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: No it wouldn't. Like any local variable, it's automatic, i.e. on the stack (unless you specify `static` or `threadlocal`, but even then it won't be dynamic). Dynamically allocating an object only means that its members are on the heap.

Comment: ah, sure, the difference to the linked question being that it's in a method and not member of a class, right, like Hugo T's answer is pointing out? thanks for the correction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing member variables with variables declared inside a member function.

```
class Foo {
  public:
    int arr[13][64][64][64]; //Will be allocated in the same memory as the instance

    void func() {
      int arr2[13][64][64][64]; //Will always be allocated on the stack
    };
};
```

So if you have `Foo* foo = new Foo()` `arr` is allocated on the heap because the whole `foo` object is allocated on the heap. On the other hand `Foo bar();` now `arr` is allocated on the stack because `bar` is allocated on the stack.

Calling either `foo->func()` or `bar.func()` will allocated the `arr1` array on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Would you expect the following function to allocate `arr` on the heap?

```
void free_func(foo * this_)
{
    double arr[13][64][64][64];
}
```

Of course you wouldn't. The function `foo:func` is no different, except that `this` is passed automatically. Whether `this` is on heap or not makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Array is allocated in `func()`'s stack frame, like it normally happens to local variables. I'm not sure though why would this code cause segfault. Unless to honor the name of this site.