# global declaration is in stack or heap?

Tags: c

I need to declare a variable that is not in the stack memory but in the heap, like below

```
struct mystruct *name;
```

Should I declare it outside all functions (even outside main()) at the begin of file?

Comment: em? variable on heap? hmmmm

Comment: C does not specify implementation details.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You can use a heap-based approach instead of a stack.

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: `static` may be useful to prevent local variables from being allocated on the stack.

Comment: Is there any alternative in case I do not want to use the 'static' keyword?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Then ask a new question about what you're trying to *accomplish*, rather than what you're trying to *figure out*.

Comment: you can also use malloc/calloc to allocate memory from heap area.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does this type of memory get allocated on the heap or the stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426737/does-this-type-of-memory-get-allocated-on-the-heap-or-the-stack)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that a variable is *never* declared "on the heap". Only memory pointed to by a pointer can be *allocated* on (from) the heap.

In your example, you can declare `name` indeed outside any function and then it will exist in global memory. You can also delcare the variable inside a function, preceded by the keyword `static`. This latter will allocate the variable also in global memory, but it will only be visible in the function where you declared it.

To use your pointer variable, you now must alocate memory for it to point to, which you allocate on the heap using `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR Version**

You cannot declare a variable such that the variable itself lives on the heap.

**James Michener Version**

The C language definition doesn't talk about stacks or heaps; it talks about *storage durations*.

Objects with `auto` storage duration (anything declared within a block and without the `static` keyword) have lifetimes that extend from the beginning of that block and end when the block exits<sup>1</sup>:

```
void foo( void )
{
  int a = 0;                        // lifetime of a extends to the end of
                                    // the function
  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )    // lifetime of i and b extend to the end
  {                                 // of the for loop
    int b = a + i;    
    printf( "b = %d\n", b );     
  }
}
```

Most implementations allocate storage for `auto` objects from the hardware stack, because a stack makes that behavior easy to implement<sup>2</sup>.

Objects with `static` storage duration (anything declared outside of a function or with the `static` keyword) have lifetimes that extend from the time the program is loaded into memory until the program exits:

```
int a = 0;                   // lifetime of a extends over the lifetime of
                             // the entire program
int main( void )
{
  static int b = 10;         // lifetime of b also extends over the lifetime
                             // of the program, but is only visible within
                             // main
  ...
}
```

Most implementations will set aside storage for `static` objects within the body of the executable itself (for an executable using the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format, such objects will be stored in the `.bss`, `.data`, or `.rodata` sections of the image).

Objects with `allocated` storage duration (anything allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`) have lifetimes that extend from the time that they are allocated until they are explicitly deallocated with a call to `free`.

```
int *foo( size_t size )
{
  int *ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr * size );  
  return ptr;                               
}

void bar( void )
{
  int *p = foo( 10 );                       
  // do something with p
  free( p );
}
```

The *variables* `ptr` and `p` only exist for the lifetimes of their respective functions, and they will be typically allocated from the stack.  The object both variables *point to* exists from the time it is allocated with `malloc` until it is deallocated with `free`.

Most implementations allocate storage for `allocated` objects from the heap.

There's really no way for you to *declare* an object that has `allocated` storage duration; the only way you can create such an object is via `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.  Whatever object you declare to store the pointer value returned by any of those functions will have either `auto` or `static` storage duration.

---

<sup>1.  In practice, storage for all local objects is allocated at function entry and released at function exit, regardless of whether the object's lifetime is over the entire function or limited to a block within the function.  However, you should never rely on that storage being accessible outside of that object's lifetime.  For example, the lifetimes of `i` and `b` are limited to the `for` loop; even though the storage for each may have been allocated at function entry, you should not attempt to access that storage outside of the loop body.


2.  C was designed on a machine with a stack, after all.</sup>